# iPhone - Edited photos reverting to original state

Tags: iphone, photos, bug

I am facing a strange phenomena on my iPhone X running iOS 11.3. Whenever I edit a photo in the Photos app, the edits simply disappear the next day. Any photos I edit, all of them revert to the original state the next day. I've also noticed, when I take a photo in the Portrait mode, it reverts to no portrait bokeh effect, as well.

Does anyone have any idea what's going on and how to fix this issue? Is it a possibly bug of iOS 11.3?

Edit: This question is not a duplicate! The issue is the same, however, the question is different

Comment: This question is not a duplicate! The issue is the same, however, the question is different.

Comment: So, how does your question differ from the duplicate question?

Comment: The mentioned question is about how to recover those edited photos (with iCloud backup enabled). My question is that how to prevent/fix this issue as it keeps happening every day (regardless iCloud).